# ME370T Nexus 7 not connecting to bluetooth device 4.1.2

Tags: bluetooth

I know nothing about programming and I can not read code, but this site kept popping up in my search regarding my bluetooth issue with my nexus 7.

I purchased the 2012 ME370T nexus 7 tablet used from a friend with android 4.4.2 OS. Research shows that the RFComm bluetooth stack for "SPP" bluetooth profiles does not work and a downgrade or revert back to 4.1.2 should fix the issue. I used a root tool kit unlock, root, and revert back to 4.1.2 (like I said, I know absolutely nothing about this) and still nothing.

I have an HKS ob-link (obd II bluetooth adapter similar to an elm327). 
The device will "pair" with my Nexus 7, but will not connect to transfer data. 
Bluetooth device uses the SPP profile for data transfer.

included is a link of what I'm talking about.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FybPbUjaxzE

here's a link to the product. 
http://www.hks-power.co.jp/en/product/electronics/monitor/ob-link/index.html

at the bottom of the product's page you can see the links to the various lists of which car the device will work with, and which tablets the device is compatible with.

I see many people on this forum are able to post codes. How are you doing that? what program are you running? Logcat? and also, I don't even know how to insert the code for my bluetooth to function.

If anyone could help I will be grateful. I'm seriously about to just trash this entire project. My Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 wouldn't connect to the device either.